# AMFPHP AMF Call doesn't return anything

Tags: php, amf, amfphp

I am trying to send a login call and return a simple array value. But I always get silence in return.

PS: I am using Flash Remoting.

This is a very old project which I have just managed to port to Amfphp 2.0.

In BackOffice browser, when I check Call AMF, it also doesn't return anything.

I have enabled `AmfphpBinaryLogger` and it records all the requests, no responses.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have a PHP error? Have you checked your PHP logs?

Comment: I have the services working perfectly in other formats inside ServiceBrowser. Its only the AMF calls, thats a problem.

Comment: The service browser allows you to make AMF calls. What happens then?

Comment: In view server's answer area its stuck at : loading...

Comment: Maybe your server has an issue with the Amfphp code itself. Like I said, have you checked the PHP logs? A packet sniffer would allow you to check for HTTP response status too. If it's 500, then it's likely a PHP error somewhere. Have a look here too http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/troubleshooting-and-debugging-your-project/

Comment: Hi, I figured out the problem. I migrated to PHP 5.4 and it solved the problem.